# Adding objects to existing array in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

In my model there are 2 functions to get data from database.  Both return data as arrays of objects.One function is given below.

```
public function get_camaramens($data,$evdata)
{
$this->db->select('emp_position.employee_id');
$this->db->from('emp_position');
$this->db->where('emp_position.position','c');
$this->db->where('emp_position.employee_id NOT IN ('.implode(",",$data).')');
$query=$this->db->get('',$evdata);
return $query->result();
}
```

In my controller I accept this result as follows.

```
$sdata['camaramen_list']    = $this->emp_position_model>get_camaramens($data,$evdata['no_of_cams']);
```

The other function in the model is

```
public function get_camara_assistants($data,$sdata,$evdata)
{
$cdata = array();
foreach($sdata['camaramen_list'] as $row) {
$cdata[] = $row->employee_id;
}

$this->db->select('emp_position.employee_id');
$this->db->from('emp_position');
$this->db->where('emp_position.position','ca');
$this->db->where('emp_position.employee_id NOT IN ('.implode(", ",$data).')');
$this->db->where('emp_position.employee_id NOT IN ('.implode(", ",$cdata).')');
$query=$this->db->get('',$evdata);
return $query->result();
}
```

In my controller I want to add the result of the above function to the same array of objects $sdata.  But if I put same name as follows it replace the previous array.

```
$sdata['camaramen_list']    = $this->emp_position_model->get_camara_assistants($data,$sdata,$evdata['no_of_cams']);
```

Can anyone tell me correct way please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the same variable, it could be override. There are two ways you can do that.

1. #### `array_merge` at Controller

   You can merge two arrays by `array_merge`.

   ```
   $result1 = $this->emp_position_model>get_camaramens($data,$evdata['no_of_cams']);
   $result2 = $this->emp_position_model->get_camara_assistants($data,$sdata,$evdata['no_of_cams']);

   $combined_result = array_merge($result1, $result2);
   ```
2. #### `UNION` select at Model

   ```
   $this->db->select('emp_position.employee_id');
   $this->db->from('emp_position');
   $this->db->where('emp_position.position','c');
   $this->db->where('emp_position.employee_id NOT IN ('.implode(",",$data).')');

   $compiled_1 = $this->db->get_compiled_select();


   $this->db->select('emp_position.employee_id');
   $this->db->from('emp_position');
   $this->db->where('emp_position.position','ca');
   $this->db->where('emp_position.employee_id NOT IN ('.implode(", ",$data).')');
   $this->db->where('emp_position.employee_id NOT IN ('.implode(", ",$cdata).')');

   $compiled_2 = $this->db->get_compiled_select();


   $query = $this->db->query('( ' .$compiled_2 .' ) UNION ALL ( '. $compiled_1 .' );' );
   ```

You can use `$sdata['camaramen_list']['one']`, `$sdata['camaramen_list']['two']` if you wanna create new index. Otherwise, use my way instead.

Hope it would be help.

Comment: Thank u very much Benyi. I tried the first one. It is succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

Try to understand the basic concept:

```
$sdata['one'] = 'some value';
```

and I want to add one more value in that array and I do it like:

```
$sdata['one'] = 'Some other value';
```

// this value overrides the old value, because you are adding the values on same index, this will override already existing value.

So do it like:

```
$sdata['old']['one'] = 'Some other value';
```

add new value like:

```
$sdata['new']['one'] = 'Some other value';
```

In this case there are two diff index old, one. So no override is done here.

or save it on some diff index.

Answer (score 0):

If both results are arrays, you can use [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) to merge one or more arrays into a new one.

```
$sdata['camaramen_list'] = array_merge(
    $this->emp_position_model->get_camaramens($data,$evdata['no_of_cams']),
    $this->emp_position_model->get_camara_assistants($data,$sdata,$evdata['no_of_cams']);
);

var_dump($sdata['camaramen_list']);//the new array
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$data['data1']= $this->emp_position_model->get_camaramens($data,$evdata['no_of_cams']);
$data2['data2']= $this->emp_position_model->get_camara_assistants($data,$sdata,$evdata['no_of_cams']);
$sdata['camaramen_list']=array_merge($data,$data2);

$this->load->view('your_view_page',$sdata['camaramen_list'] );
```